# how to load custom mib file to snmpd agent

Tags: snmp, snmpd

I'm running snmpd in docker (polinux/snmpd:alpine image) and I want to use my custom mib file with my OIDs objects of different data types that I prepared for testing purposes and validated it by 2 different online mib validators then I fixed all errors that they pointed out to me and now my file should be ok, but I still can't find my oids by snmpwalk or my module by snmptranslate.
Here is what I tried:

1. pass `-m <mib file>` or/and `-M <mibs dir>` arguments to snmpd - didn't work
2. add

> ```
> mibdirs +/etc/snmpd/
> mibs +ALL
> ```

to the snmpd.conf file - didn't work either

Am I missing something? What could be wrong?

My mib:

```
MY-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
    MODULE-IDENTITY,
    OBJECT-TYPE,
    Counter32,
    Counter64,
    Gauge32,
    TimeTicks,
    IpAddress
        FROM SNMPv2-SMI
        DisplayString, TimeStamp
        FROM SNMPv2-TC
        OBJECT-GROUP
        FROM SNMPv2-CONF;

myMIB MODULE-IDENTITY
    LAST-UPDATED "202310110000Z"
    ORGANIZATION "My Organization"
    CONTACT-INFO "contact@example.com"
    DESCRIPTION "Example Custom MIB"
    REVISION "202310110000Z"
    DESCRIPTION "Initial revision"
    ::= { iso(1) identified-organization(3) dod(6) internet(1) private(4) enterprises(1) 9999 }
    
myObjects OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { myMIB 1 }
    
myObjectGroup OBJECT-GROUP
    OBJECTS { myBits,
              myCounter32,
              myCounter64,
              myGauge,
              myInteger,
              myIpAddress,
              myOctetString,
              myString,
              myTimeTicks }
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "A group of my objects."
    ::= { myMIB 2 }

myString OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      DisplayString
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION "Example scalar object"
    DEFVAL { "example" }
    ::= { myObjects 1 }


myInteger OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      INTEGER
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION "Example integer object"
    DEFVAL { 1 }
    ::= { myObjects 2 }


myCounter32 OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Counter32
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION "Example counter object"
    ::= { myObjects 3 }


myCounter64 OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Counter64
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION "Example counter object"
    ::= { myObjects 4 }


myGauge OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Gauge32
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION "Example gauge object"
    DEFVAL { 1 }
    ::= { myObjects 5 }


myTimeTicks OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      TimeTicks
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION "Example timeticks object"
    DEFVAL { 1 }
    ::= { myObjects 6 }


myIpAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX IpAddress
    MAX-ACCESS read-write
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION "My IPADDRESS object"
    DEFVAL { 'c0210415'H } -- 192.33.4.21
    ::= { myObjects 7 }


myOctetString OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX OCTET STRING (SIZE(0..255))
    MAX-ACCESS read-write
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION "My OCTET STRING object"
    DEFVAL { "255" }
    ::= { myObjects 8 }


myBits OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX BITS {
                bit1(0),
                bit2(1),
                bit3(2)
            }
    MAX-ACCESS read-write
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION "My BITS object"
    DEFVAL { { bit1 } }
    ::= { myObjects 9 }


END
```

Comment: You need the right tools for the right tasks. To develop a custom SNMP agent, you might learn how to extend snmpd with your custom MIB documents (mib2c and others are required). To just simulate the objects, snmpsim from PySNMP might help. Your real goals matter more than the contents above.

Comment: @LexLi, hi, I'm trying to use snmpsim from your advice, could you please help me to understand if you know if I can an add oid with data type "bits" in .snmprec file for agent data simulation? because in the list of tags I haven't find any tags for this data type. Is it unsupported?

Comment: Grab an essential book on SNMP so that you can study the data types further. There isn't a primitive `BITS` type, but a derived type from `OCTET STRING`.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably not the best answer, but it works.

Put MIB file in /usr/share/snmp/mibs

snmp.conf:
mibs +MY-MIB

I have never gotten the mibdirs directive to work

Comment: Probably not even an answer.